# JavaScript closure: uncaught reference

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm new to JS. I try the function closure, just as in the documentation example and I get an uncaught reference. Why?

```
function fetchData(filter) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "my_url"+route,
        data: filter
      });
};

function fetchDataSource(filter) {
  var route = "data_source";
  return fetchData(filter);
};
```

And now, when I call the function:

```
var filter;
fetchData(filter);
```

I have the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: route is not defined
>       at fetchData (:6:49)
>       at fetchDataSource (:3:10)
>       at :1:1

Why is route not visible in my function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fetchData function does not include route in its closure because route is defined inside a sibling function. There are ways to make it closure around route as you would expect, somethign like this would work:

```
var route;

function fetchData(filter) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "my_url"+route,
        data: filter
      });
};

function fetchDataSource(filter) {
  route = "data_source";
  return fetchData(filter);
};
```

Because route is defined in the scope that *contains* fetchData here, whereas it's not in yours.